# PV voltage on solar charge controller always 13V

Tags: solar-cell, solar-charge-controller

I just wired a solar panel with solar charge controller (SCC) and battery.

The  photovoltaic (PV) voltage displayed on the SCC is 13V, even though the PV voltage without load that I measured with a voltmeter is 19V.

After that I tried to put two PV panels in series and I measured again and got 39V.

But after I installed SCC with battery and connected the PV panels, the SCC still shows the PV voltage at 13V. I measured with a voltmeter and got the same 13V.

Is there a problem with my SCC or my PV panels?

Comment: Please provide a diagram of how you have things connected and where you measured which voltages.

Comment: PV to solar cell port on scc and battery to battery port on scc. I parallel voltmeter at solar cell port on scc.

Comment: That's how a solar charge controller works.  Look at the PV panels as power sources rather than voltage.  If you use two in series you need a 24 V controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Solar panel voltage is being held to 13V because it is supplying current to the battery to charge it.

That is expected behavior, and not at all harmful to the panel.

As the battery reaches full charge the load on the panel will reduce and its voltage will rise.

Some designs of solar charge controllers will control the power by diverting the panel power into either a resistor or a short circuit in which case the panel voltage may reduce or even cyclically pulse to zero.